# Emacs: Opening a file within the same Emacs session from a tmux session in ansi-term

Tags: session, emacs, ansi-term

I often come across the situation where I want to open a file that I am viewing from my tmux session in ansi-term into my Emacs session. I tried to use `find-file-at-point` (see `Max Bozzi`'s answer below), but in tmux it only directs me to the working directory of my ansi-term session, and it does not detect the file in my tmux session. With ansi-term alone, `find-file-at-point` works fine, but I prefer to use a session manager, or at least a solid terminal multiplexer.

Any suggestions?

For example, here is my tmux session in ansi-term:

```
lucas@~/Downloads$ ls
A CHRISTMAS CAROL (ILLUSTRATED with Special Kindle Format).azw3
bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1310.deb
Island of the Blue Dolphins.azw3
javaPong.jnlp
test.txt
```

How do I open `test.txt` within my Emacs session?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to place point on the name of the file and then run `find-file-at-point`. I find that to be useful enough to bind to `M-'`.

Another is to just use the standard `C-c C-f` and tab-complete the name, or maybe if you really wanted to, to have recursive Emacs and have Emacs running inside Emacs' own terminal buffer.  Presumably you wouldn't, though, so I would stick to `find-file-at-point`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but it does not work for my tmux session , which I usually run inside ansi-term. `find-file-at-point` only directs me to the working directory of my ansi-term session, and it does not detect anything in my tmux session. Any suggestions?